# jQuery Month picker dropdown dialog misaligned when zoomed in or zoomed out a webpage (refer the 3 images given)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css-position

Observe these three images.

**zoom 100%**
[image: zoom 100%]

**zoom 110%**
[image: zoom 110%]

**zoom 90%**
[image: zoom 90%]

you can see it live [here](https://kidsysco.github.io/jquery-ui-month-picker/), just open any monthpicker dialog & perfrom zoom-in zoom-out.

My question is, what can we do, so that the monthpicker dialog will always stay attached to the input feild.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would also be best to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/Tour

Comment: You can see it here(https://kidsysco.github.io/jquery-ui-month-picker/). Open the link & click on any calendar icon, do the zoom-in & zoom-out &  you will get to see the problem.

Comment: Might need to redraw or re-spawn the calendar when you resize the window. Will see if I can setup an example. Also this might be a Bug with the 
jquery-ui-month-picker that may need to be reported on the GitHub instead of in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [this line](https://github.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker/blob/6bf5fcb6a38b07206162383468283e68d3e10e97/src/MonthPicker.js#L408)

Changed

```js
_menu.appendTo( isInline ? _el : document.body );
```

to

```js
_menu.appendTo( isInline ? document.body : _el.parent());
```

and it worked!